# (Java) How can I count the number of tab and space before the first character of a string

Tags: java

(Java) How can I count the number of tab and space before the first character of a string

Assume that a string
`String line = "        Java is good."`

There are totally 10 spaces in this string.
However, how can I count the number of tab and space before the first character "J" only?
There are 8 spaces before the first character "J" only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
    String s = "        Java is good.";
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        total++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

Or

```
    String s = "        Java is good.";
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char ch = s.charAt(i);
      if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t') {
        total++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: Your answer is the fastest answer. You really solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex replacement length trick here:

```java
String line = "\t   \t  Java is good.";
int numSpaces = line.length() - line.replaceAll("^[\t ]+", "").length();
System.out.println(numSpaces);  // 7
```

Answer (score 0):

For a project which uses the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library, the `CharMatcher` class can determine this:

```java
int count = CharMatcher.noneOf(" \t").indexIn(line);
```

If the string does not contain a non-space, non-tab character, `-1` is returned.  Depending on the desired behavior, this special value can be checked for and an appropriate value returned.

Answer (score 0):

For a project which uses the [StreamEx](https://github.com/google/guava) library, the [`IntStreamEx.indexOf()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#indexOf(int)) method can determine this:

```java
long count = IntStreamEx.ofChars(line).indexOf(c -> c != ' ' && c != '\t')
        .orElse(line.length());
```

If the string does not contain a non-space, non-tab character, the length of the string is returned.  This behavior can be changed by returning a different value from `.orElse` or otherwise changing how the `OptionalLong` value is accessed.

Answer (score -1):

There is a trim method which removes leading and trailing whitespaces.
If you were positive there was only leading whitespace and not trailing, you could compare the length of the non-trimmed with the trimmed.

`

```
int diff = line.length - line.trim().length;
```

`

```
Or just count with a for loop

`

int spaces = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < line.length; x++){
    if(line[x].equals(" ")){
        spaces++;
    }else break;
}
```

`